# Unable to send Mails using Java Mail API [Using Gmail]

Tags: java, email, smtp, gmail

**I have used following code which was working fine in year 2014 but currently its not working.**

Credentials used in this code are also correct.

```
public class SendMail 
{  
public void SendMailToTheUserWhoHaveForgotThePassword(String MailTo,String Password)
  {      
      String to = MailTo;  
      String from = "chatna06062016@gmail.com";
      final String username = "chatna06062016";     
      final String password = "xxxxxxxx";  

      String host = "smtp.gmail.com";  
      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); 
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);   
      props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");  
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator() 
                    {             
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
                        {                
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);     
                        }          
                    }
                                            );  

      try 
      {   
          Message message = new MimeMessage(session);            
          message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));       
          message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(to));        
          message.setSubject("FORGOTTEN PASSWORD"); 


          message.setText("Dear User The Password that you have forgotten is <b>"+Password +"</b>"+ 
                "This email is sended you by using JavaMailAPI "
                  + "HAVE A NICE DAY"
                  + "DO USE THIS SERVICE WHENEVER YOU NEED IT");  

    Transport.send(message);  
      System.out.println("Sent message successfully...."); 

      }
      catch (MessagingException e) { 
         throw new RuntimeException(e); 
      }

       }

}
```

**I have got email from google like this on the usage of the method used in above class.**

[image: Email Received from Google]

```
Hi ChatNa,
Someone just tried to sign in to your Google Account chatna06062016@gmail.com from an app that doesn't meet modern security standards.
    Details:
Sunday, June 26, 2016 12:57 PM (India Standard Time)
Noida, Uttar Pradesh, India*
We strongly recommend that you use a secure app, like Gmail, to access your account. All apps made by Google meet these security standards. Using a less secure app, on the other hand, could leave your account vulnerable. Learn more.

Google stopped this sign-in attempt, but you should review your recently used devices:
```

What to do now unable to find out anything helpful anywhere.

Comment: GMail wants you to be more secured by using SSL/TLS protocols. Swtich to use port 456 or 587 and add necessary properties to set up a secured mail connection.

Comment: any example @glee8e

Comment: I suppose there will be some on Google. I'm using a smart phone and it would be troublesome to code with a smart phone.

Comment: no problem buddy @glee8e your comment is be very helpful to me as you have given me a hint to solve this problem which is enough for me to solve this problem.

Comment: did you find what are the settings needed to make this work with gmail? I just ran into the same problem...

Answer (score 3):

you may need to do following setting in the gmail account:

goto :
myaccount -> signIn & security -> connected apps & sites -> Allow less secure apps: ON

Comment: This works but it will make my gmail account less secure.

Comment: unfortunately this the security restriction added by gmail.

Comment: @HarshSharma yes enabling less secure apps make your account more vulnerable to attack.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that you are logging directly into the SMTP/IMAP mail server using the users login and password.  This is not secure.

You should consider switching to useing  [XOauth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol) then you can verify your application and it will no longer be considered insecure.

> The XOAUTH2 mechanism allows clients to send OAuth 2.0 access tokens to the server. The protocol uses encoded values shown in the following sections.

```
    [connection begins]
    C: C01 CAPABILITY
    S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA XLIST
    CHILDREN XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=XOAUTH
    S: C01 OK Completed
    C: A01 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 dXNlcj1zb21ldXNlckBleGFtcGxlLmNvb
    QFhdXRoPUJlYXJlciB5YTI5LnZGOWRmdDRxbVRjMk52YjNSbGNrQmhkSFJoZG
    1semRHRXVZMjl0Q2cBAQ==
    S: A01 OK Success
    [connection continues...]
```

Option number to was mentioned by others Just enable less secure apps. You can read all about it here [Less secure apps & your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) and the dangers associated with enabling it.